# Python: socket.recv is missing significant amount of data

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I've read varios threads where people had similar errors but I coulnd't solve my specific instance of the error.
I am trying to send a file with size 220700 bytes from a linux-computer to my windows laptop.

On my linux machine:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 65432))
    while True:
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            conn.sendall(os.path.getsize(csi_file_path).to_bytes(8, 'big'))
            sent_bytes = conn.sendfile(open(csi_file_path, "r+b"))
            print(f"Sent {sent_bytes} bytes")
            conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

on my windows machine:

```
def receive_byte_array(sckt, expected_size=0):
    response = bytearray()
    while len(response) < expected_size:
        chunk = sckt.recv(expected_size - len(response))
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        print(f"Received chunk of size {len(chunk)}")
        response.extend(chunk)
    return response

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((con_details.get("HOST"), con_details.get("PORT")))
    s.settimeout(20.0)
    incoming_length = int.from_bytes(receive_byte_array(s, 8), "big")
    cir_data = receive_byte_array(s, incoming_length)
```

My linux machine says it has sent 220700 bytes but I am only receiving 55000 (or 67000, sometimes 80000, seems pretty random) on my windows machine.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: You may try to reduce the recv buffer like:`chunk = sckt.recv(1024)`.

Comment: @maciek97x I already tried that, didn't help

Comment: You can also check sent packets using Wireshark or similar tool to determine on which side there is an error.

Comment: How do you know you're *...only receiving 55000 (or 67000...)*? `receive_byte_array()` won't return until it receives the expected size. What happens if you don't set a timeout on the socket?

Comment: Show us what is printed by your 2 print statements. Show also exceptions, if any.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike `receive_byte_array` returns if chunk-size is 0 (this indicates that the receive buffer is empty and there is nothing more to be received).

Comment: @user3435121 The print statement on the linux machine prints the proper file size while the print statement on the windows machine prints the individual chunk size, summing to whatever WRONG amount

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the client (the linux machine) closed the socket once the execution reached the end of the `with conn` block even though not all of the data was transmitted (or stored in the transmit buffer even). If I keep the connection open, e.g. with a `conn.recv(4096)`, I receive all the data on my windows machine.

Comment: Impossible. The client could have *reset* the connection to achieve that effect, but if it did a normal close all data in flight would be preserved.

Comment: The socket is created within a `with` - statement. So I guess it makes sense that the socket is closed once the last statement within that `with`-block returns

Comment: @user207421 How would a reset look like? Why would that happen?